# Buzzing sound when playing Youtube videos

Tags: sound

When I click on a video to play, it plays perfectly, even in tablet mode. I have an ASUD T100a, and Ubuntu 21.10 It plays for 3 or 4 minutes then some sort of buffer overflows and it starts buzzing. then after a while, the video freezes. Then if you click mute to stop the annoying microphone feedback sound coming through the speakers the video starts playing again but the annoying sound continues. You have to get out and get back in again to start playing the video again but this time the sound comes back ever faster, maybe 2 minutes this time. My question is how can this be hardware if it works ....at first. It's like saying an electrician who wires a circuit wrong then when you turn the lights on it comes on for a while then goes out. WRONG. If it's wired wrong it trips the breaker right away, it docent work for a while then after a while decides to stop working. So why does this work for a while and then quit? I am wondering if its something to do with the browser and buffering or if maybe an ad is trying to play in the background at the same time a video is playing. The reason why is one time I let it buzz for a long time to see if it ever stops and it does. Just let it buzz for about 5 or 6 minutes then it just stops and after 5 or 6 more minutes it starts buzzing again and then the video stops playing until you click mute, then it plays with the sound as a buzzing feedback-like sound. This also happens on my Surface 3 with Ubuntu. Is there something to look for in the browser? I use Brave and Firefox, same things happen on both. This has been going on for over 5 months now. I even tried switching to Fedora, Manjaro, Mint, etc. Nothing fixes this sound problem.

I did notice something else. On the platform that plays videos and works the little 10-second times that clicks down to 0 and then asks to "Skip ads" is NOT there on the ones where it buzzes. In the one where it does not buzz the ad plays and shows the box to skip. On the ones where it buzzes then is no ad box and even no ads at all. Not even the opening ad. This must be trying to play and it's not being handled. It must be about the ads and how they are handled.

This is the more details that someone is looking for. I have no idea what they want but maybe just randomly typing is what they are looking for. Especially since there is absolutely no detailed feedback as to what this fool is looking for, just play god and reject things but not give any reason why. I guess I will just go to the cut-and-paste method and blast this a couple of hundred times so that maybe one of them will go through. I get it now. It's a numbers game.

Comment: AFAIK, it has something to do with your browser or your driver. Try switching kernels or try a different browser (recommend switching your browser first).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did try Firefox and Brave but I guess I could try Chrome. I dont know how secure Chrome is on Linux, I mean the whole point of me switching to linux was to get away from those guys but i can try it just to see if it works. Thanks again.